# Not able to save Base64 Image using carrierwave gem in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, carrierwave

I want to save a image in base64 format sent by mobile device in my database. I have tried to install carrierwave-base64 Gem but no use. Can any one suggest me the right way to do it? I have tried all possible ways. I want clear code to upload a base64 image using carrierwave Gem.

Comment: provide a minimal working example

Comment: I have installed https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64 this gem . But still the image saving as blank.